# slickgrid scroll action triggers call back to refresh table set

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, callback, slickgrid

I am currently facing this problem that I tried to use different approach to solve it, but I am currently stuck. (I am using angular and slickgrid)

I want to display a partial data from a large dataset that is enough to fit in a grid, because I want to have lazy loading. I have a event listens to the onScroll event, so it triggers $http call with parameter when someone scroll the bar. Say I scrolled the bar to a position, I will retrieve the data from backend start with the position towards the end of the grid in the viewport. And It need to render back to the view with respected position. Here is a simple example to illustrate what I want to achieve, the real application the data returned is dynamically.

```
var options = {
enableCellNavigation: true,
enableColumnReorder: false,
enableCellNavigation: true,
asyncEditorLoading: false,
enableAsyncPostRender: true
 };

//$http call to retrieve data from row 1 to row 27, and display in the grid
DataService.setData(0, //plus soem other data)

//watch the variable, when getData is set
$scope.$watch(function(return DataService.getData() function(newData)
{
  var grid;
var columns = [
{id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title"},
{id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"}
];


var data = [];
for (var i = newData["rowID"]; i < newData.length; i++) {
  data[i] = {
    title: newData["name"],
    duration: newData["duration"]
  };
}


grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

grid.onScroll.subscribe(function(e, args){
    //http call to retrieve the data
    //!!issue with args.scrollTop is that it does not get the row number of grid, but pixel wide position. I tried with args.row and few other funcs but no help
    DataService.setData(args.scrollTop(), //plus some other data);
});
});
```

I don't have the actual code with me, but if you get what I mean, can you please point me to a right direction to do it. Because I don't see anyone doing similar functionality that I could learn from. New to slickgrid, and want to learn, thanks.

+, I have also tried to use asyncPostRender, but by using that, every single cell need to be called to render the grid in the viewport, which I want to create a feeling that the user is actually scroll the whole set of data, without loading delays. So whole grid refresh in the viewport will be useful.

Comment: I am willing to add any additional content, if my explanation is not clear. Thanks alot

Comment: You are headed in the right direction, but you are overwriting your existing data. You need to add data to the dataView each time you scroll down. SlickGrid has an example that is currently not working, but you can checkout the way the creator suggested to do it using the RemoteModel - https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example6-ajax-loading.html. Otherwise I have implemented an infinite scroll myself using the dataView functionality -> https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView#updating-data. You basically addItems to it and it automatically adds them.